# Ubuntu 17.10 Display manager drag'n'drop broken

Tags: display, 17.10, bug-reporting, drag-and-drop

I have three displays, but I cannot rearrange displays in the display manager (Displays "app") because the drag'n'drop is not working. I see the drag symbol as cursor but displays will not move, which means I cannot rearrange the displays at all.